# ASP.NET C# - Old School Login Page w/ Roll your own authentication scheme via AppBase.BaseLogin class

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, authentication, active-directory

I'm trying to setup code to check the username and password with values in the database and the user's role as either (agent user, marketer, or admin) and load the Page\USMap.aspx page accordingly.  The website performs a search for insurance plans based off state and zip. Admin users will have access to an admin page to create new users and allow users access to certain states for the search and that is it.

Problem: I need the code-behind for the login page. I want to clean up the code from the old site, take out any references to appBase, make the code work with the new site and old database, and take out references to creating any temp tables out but I'm not sure what all this mess of code does and I'm not too familiar with authentication. I believe the old site used IIS Active Directory Authentication? How do I Set that up for the new site. For the new site, I'm just working off a C# template for a web application. Is there anything better I should use?  I don't see where the code actually checks and vaildates the username and password in the database....

Additional info: Error Received: The type or namespace name 'name' does not exist in the namespace 'namespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?) for BaseLogin when I put AppBase.BaseLogin in the new project. What else do i need to add to make this work? 
Here's the code from the old site that needs to be cleaned up:

```
public partial class SignIn : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Put user code to initialize the page here
        string userName;
        string passWord;
        userName = Request.QueryString["u"];
        passWord = Request.QueryString["p"];
        if (userName!=null && passWord!=null)
        {
            Login(DecryString(userName.Trim()),DecryString(passWord.Trim()));
            return;
        }
        string ls_redirectpage="";
        int iCondition=0;
        if (userName!=null)
        {
            iCondition = userName.LastIndexOf("\\");
            userName = userName.Substring(iCondition+1,userName.Length-iCondition-1);               
        }

        if (userName!="" && userName!=null)
        {
            //show check the database
            AppBase.BaseLogin lg = new AppBase.BaseLogin();
            if (lg.SignIn(userName,passWord))
            {
                lg = null;

                ls_redirectpage = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RedirectPage");
                if ((ls_redirectpage==null) || (ls_redirectpage==""))
                {
                    msg.Text = "Please setup 'RedirectPage' in the web.config.";
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(ls_redirectpage);
                }
            }
            lg = null;
        }
    }
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void login()
    {
        bool lb_ok = false;
        string  ls_username,ls_password, ls_sql;
        string  ls_redirectpage="";
        int     li_rows=0;
        ls_username = username.Text;
        ls_password = password.Text;
        ls_username = ls_username.Trim();
        ls_password = ls_password.Trim();
        ls_sql = "ssp_sign_in_web_common";
        System.Data.DataTable dt ;
        AppBase.BaseDbCommon dc = new AppBase.BaseDbCommon();
        System.Collections.ArrayList ao_parm = new System.Collections.ArrayList (2);
        ao_parm.Add (dc.MakeOleInParm("as_username",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,ls_username));
        ao_parm.Add (dc.MakeOleInParm("as_password",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,ls_password));

        dt = dc.GetOleDataTable(ls_sql,ao_parm,dc.GetOleConnection());
        dc = null;
        if (dt!=null)
        {
            li_rows = dt.Rows.Count;
            if (li_rows !=1)
            {
                lb_ok = false;
                goto condition;
            }

            if (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.GetUpperBound(0)!=5)
                lb_ok = false;
            else
                lb_ok = true;
        }
        else
            lb_ok = false;

        condition:

        if (lb_ok)
        {
            if ((dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString()=="1") || (dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString()=="Y"))
            {
                Session["LogonId"]      = ls_username;
                Session["PassWord"]     = ls_password;
                Session["FirstName"]    = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                Session["LastName"]     = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                Session["Email"]        = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                Session["AdminFlag"]    = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                Session["LoginType"]    = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString();

                ls_redirectpage = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RedirectPage");
                if ((ls_redirectpage==null) || (ls_redirectpage==""))
                {
                    msg.Text = "Please setup 'RedirectPage' in the web.config.";
                }
                else
                {
                    dc = null;
                    dt = null;
                    Response.Redirect(ls_redirectpage);
                }
            }
            else
                msg.Text = "You are not an active account now. please contact admin.";
        }
        else
        {
            msg.Text = "Please check your user ID and password.";
        }
        dc = null;
        dt = null;
    }
    #region Web Form Designer generated code
    override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
        //
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    ///     the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ImageButton1.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(this.ImageButton1_Click);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);

    }
    #endregion

    private void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        string  ls_username,ls_password;


        ls_username = username.Text;
        ls_password = password.Text;
        ls_username = ls_username.Trim();
        ls_password = ls_password.Trim();
        Login(ls_username,ls_password);
    }
    private void Login(string user,string pass)
    {
        string ls_redirectpage;
        bool lb_signin=false;
        AppBase.BaseLogin lg = new AppBase.BaseLogin();

        lb_signin = lg.SignIn(user,pass,msg,Session);           
        lg = null;

        if (lb_signin)
        {
            ls_redirectpage = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RedirectPage");
            string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("VirtualDirectory");
            if (path.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                if (ls_redirectpage.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                    ls_redirectpage = ls_redirectpage.Substring(1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!ls_redirectpage.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                    ls_redirectpage = "/"+ls_redirectpage;
                }
            }
            path = path + ls_redirectpage;
            Response.Redirect(path);
            ;
        }
    }
    private string DecryString(string as_source)
    {
        int li_len;
        string temp,sTarget;
        char b;
        sTarget = "";
        temp = "";
        li_len = as_source.Length;
        if (li_len < 1) return "";
        for (int li_i=0;li_i<li_len;li_i++)
        {
            temp = as_source.Substring(li_i,1);
            if ((int)temp.ToCharArray()[0]>96)
            {
                b = (char)(219 - (temp.ToCharArray())[0]);
                sTarget = sTarget + b.ToString();
            }
            else if((int)temp.ToCharArray()[0]>64 && (int)temp.ToCharArray()[0]<91)
            {
                b = (char)(155 - (temp.ToCharArray())[0]);
                sTarget = sTarget + b.ToString();
            }
            else if((int)temp.ToCharArray()[0]>47 && (int)temp.ToCharArray()[0]<58)
            {
                b = (char)(105 - (temp.ToCharArray())[0]);
                sTarget = sTarget + b.ToString();
            }       
            else
                sTarget = sTarget+temp;
        }
        return sTarget;
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! If you need any other info, let me know. 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above demonstrates a complete roll your own authentication scheme.  The magic of the login is in your AppBase.BaseLogin class.  That class would have to be responsible for checking the username & password, and persisting the log in status somehow (cookie, session, database..)

It's impossible to say - looking at this code, why the project didn't use forms authentication.  The code may be quite old (ie. pre ASP.NET 2.0), before the provider framework was put into place.  In which case, this may have been the only way to get the desired behavior.  You should be able to replace everything done here with a mixture of forms authentication, and a custom membership provider.  Again, it really is impossible to say without knowing a lot more about your project.

Comment: @Tony, I got the error: The type or namespace name 'name' does not exist in the namespace 'namespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?) for BaseLogin when I put AppBase.BaseLogin in the new project. What else do i need to add to make this work? The website performs a search for insurance plans based off state and zip. Admin users will have access to an admin page to create new users and allow users access to certain states for the search and that is it.

Comment: @Tony, so what do i get rid of in this code and keep? How do I setup forms authentication? This website was created 2 years ago but was poorly coded.

Comment: @Brian Open the original project and find out where AppBase.BaseLogin is.  (you can right click, go to definition).  It's probably in a separate assembly that needs to be referenced.  As for using forms auth, asp.net is a great resource with lots of how to style content.  A quick look uncovered the following - http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-secure-my-site-using-membership-and-roles

Comment: @Tony, I ended up adding 3 cs files under the App_Data folder to fix problematic associations. I'd rather not go with old .net 2.0 based security if I'm going to be redoing the website and go with the newer forms authentication. That video is so old and uses visual web developer express 05 haha. Is there a video that uses the visual studio 08 or 10 atleast? How would I setup the forms authentication u recommend?

Comment: That video is old, but the auth mechanism hasn't changed.  The login controls, everything is pretty much the same, including how to create your own provider.  It may be 6 years old, but it's still valid.

Comment: @Tony, when I am doing the tuturial exercie, I'm getting the following error when I click on the security tab under the asp.net website administration tool: There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

Comment: @Brian That code looks ok for standard forms auth, but it's not taking advantage of any ASP.NET 2.0 features like the login control, and doesn't show you anything related to custom role and membership providers.  Almost any ASP.NET book written in the past few years will cover this topic, and there's lots of content on ASP.NET and related sites.  Just search for custom membership provider.

Comment: @Tony, can you send me a link to a forms authentication code that uses the role and membership provider? All the ones i find are in vb.net unfortunately....

Comment: Take a look at this blog series from ScottGu. - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx