# ASP.NET - Web.config login error Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, forms-authentication

I'm using forms authentication and gettnig the following error:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find
>   stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure
>   'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) +2030802
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009584
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2275
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +215
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async) +987
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +178
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
>   System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckSchemaVersion(ProviderBase provider,
>   SqlConnection connection, String[] features, String version, Int32&
>   schemaVersionCheck) +392
>   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckSchemaVersion(SqlConnection
>   connection) +84
>   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String
>   username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String&
>   password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32&
>   failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
>   Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime&
>   lastActivityDate) +827
>   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String
>   username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate,
>   Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
>   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
>   username, String password) +106
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs
>   e) +60
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs
>   e) +129    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +127
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs
>   e) +101    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +167
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5563

here's my code on my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OleConnectionStringSource" connectionString="Data Source=alg-sql01;Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;User ID=PriceFinderUser;Password=******;Integrated Security=false"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="OleConnectionStringTarget" connectionString="Data Source=alg-sql01;Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;User ID=PriceFinderUser;Password=******;Integrated Security=false"
     providerName="System.Data.OleDb;" />
    <add name="PriceFinderConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=alg-sql01;Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PriceFinderConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=alg-sql01;Initial Catalog=PriceFinder;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

 <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="OleConnectionStringSource"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />  
  </providers>
</membership> 

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
   <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/> 
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" /> 
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

how do i fix this error? do u need to see any of the other files?
thanks!

Comment: What are the values for the two connection strings you're referencing - OleConnectionStringSource and ApplicationServices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you created the tables and stored procedures in your SQL-Server?

Have a look [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx) and execute `aspnet_regsql.exe` if you are using MS Sql-Server as DBMS.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for your response. The db is on sql server 05. I executed the aspnet_regsql.exe but I'm not sure how to bring up the ASP.NET Admin MMC Snap-in window. I still am getting that error.

Comment: @Brian: do you mean the ASP.Net Website Administration Tool? Have  a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx Were the tables and other DB-Objects successfully created?

Comment: @Tim, how do I check for that? The database i'm using already works and is fully functional with an old asp.net website but i'm using forms auth security for this site.

Comment: @Brian: is the database where you have created the asp.net tables with `aspnet_regsql.exe` the same as your connectionstring `OleConnectionStringSource`? Here are more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Comment: @Tim, I'm not sure if it really created any tables... I ran the aspnet_regsql.exe utility under  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.xyz directory per the instructions and i selected the pricefinder db under the alg-sql01 server just like it appears on the connection string

Comment: @Brian: you are on .NET Framework < 4? I ask because there is also a aspnet_regsql.exe under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.x". To verify if the tables and SP are created you only have to open SSMS and have a look in this database if there are tables that begin with the prefix `aspnet_`.

Comment: You can configure your datasource in web.config as described in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) or use the Website Administration Tool that changes your web.config automatically.

Comment: @Tim, Well I went into the v4.0 folder and that worked! thanks! my code says targetFramework="4.0" but the example said to go into framework 2.0 folder haha. The only problem is, the login form is not passing the login username value correctly and coming up with the error- Can't Login User ''. If you have time, Please check my other post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183194/asp-net-c-code-behind-on-login-page and see if you can help me out on finding a good code-behind for the login page that handles forms authentication and the custom membership provider.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved similar error 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion' in `.NET 4` as a result of missing attribute **Initial Catalog** in connection string. Either missing stored procedure or invalid connection string is causing membership provider error.